# Create Deep Link to a specific Tab in Custom MS Teams App from Activity Feed Notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a custom MS Teams app with multiple tabs. How do I make a deep link from activity feed notification to one of those tabs of the custom MS Teams app?

I currently have the following payload which links to my custom MS Teams app:

```
"Topic": {
    "source": "entityUrl",
    "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{appId}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained quite well in the [Deep link to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) page in the docs. I've linked here directly to the section that's relevant to you. You need to use the app Id that's defined in your manifest file for `<appId>` as well as the entity Id you defined in the manifest as well for your specific tab (that's really what that entity Id is used for) for the `<entityId>`. Optionally there are other parameters you can pass as well in the context, e.g. if you want your tab to open a specific item from the database for instance.